# Shopify - Log on to customer account

Tags: php, shopify

I am developing  a shopify application with the help of shopify API.

I need to check the user name and password entered is correct with shopify API.Is it possible to check this?

I do not have any solution from here:
https://docs.shopify.com/api/customer

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not possible due to security concerns. Why do you need to check if the user / password is correct or not external to shopify?

Comment: It is a mobile application,so i need to log in from app and create order

Comment: @Shijin Can't you use any other database to store this information and check on the fly?